# Copy Formatted Text and PAste with Format

Tags: vba, format, selection

Working with WORD2010 under windows 10, I want to copy all captions of the figures of an article and arrange them as a list at the end of the text.

I tried first the way by an array. I copied figure captions as strings by Selection.formattedText, put them into an array and used Selection.typeText to insert the strings at the end of the word document as a list.
Naturally, the problem is that the format e.g. symbol for a Greek alpha and a subscript letter is not kept.
Therefore, I wanted to use Selection.CopyFormat and then selection.replacement.text = Selection.FormattedText. Off course the same problem.
In principle, it seems to work because pasting the text directly after copying it gaves the write format.
However, I want to copy it, then search a certain "dummy"-string (Figure_XX_1) at the end of the document, and replace the selected dummy string by the copied text. In this case I always get the last code inserted that I copied (before starting the macro) in the clip board instead of my copied text. I wonder why this happens..

```
Sub Makro1()
'
   Selection.WholeStory
   With Selection
    .EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
    .InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    .InsertAfter ("Titles of Figures" & Chr(13) & "Figure_XX_1")&Chr(13)
    End With
   ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(12).Select
  Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToField, Which:=wdGoToNext, Count:=1, Name:="SEQ Figure *"
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select ' select figure caption        
    Selection.CopyFormat      ' copy figure caption

    With Selection
    .Find.Text = "Figure_XX_1"
    .Find.Execute
    .PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
    End With            
  End Sub
```

Can anybody help me to insert the formatted text copied?? I don't like to program with selection but don't see another way to keep the format....
Is there a way to keep the greek letters by unicode perhaps? 
Then I would treat the subscript problem separately by verifying substcript afterward by some code.
Or is there a way to make the code above running in the desired way??

Thanks very much..

Comment: At the end of your text insert an empty field CTRL+F9.  Inside the field put 'toc \t "Caption,1" \n'. Press F9 to generate the TOC (the \n turns off page numbers ). This advice assumes that your article is a Word document and that the style used to insert Captions has used the Caption Style.

Comment: Thanks for your great idea. At first I didn't understand it all how this should work and it did not work, probably due to the fact that it searched for the German word "Abbildung" instead of "Figure" but I got the idea. So I adapted it and it works great. As I did not think at all at such possibility proves probably that I near nearly never put a table of figures in my text for at least 20 years.... Thanks for this idea "out of the box"...

Comment: I am astonished that even different styles in the caption do not disturb although the style of the caption is generally fixed. Thanks for this solution.